# RetroFont.Parse recibe dos parametros pero no se que funcion cumple el primero

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phaser3

Estoy aprendiendo phaser 3 pero me quede en la parte de Phaser.GameObjects.RetroFont.Parse() recibi dos objetos, mi problema es que no se que función hace this, osea se que this toma un objeto pero que objeto toma? en segundo parametro se que esta tomando el objeto config pero no se que objeto toma this.

```js
class Bootloader extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super(); 
    }

    preload() {
        this.load.path = './assets/';
        this.load.image('gamma', 'gamma.png');
        this.load.json('gamma_json', 'gamma.json');
    }

    create() {
        let config = this.cache.json.get('gamma_json');
        
        /*Se puede ver que Phaser.GameObjects.RetroFont.Parse() recibe dos objetos, se
        que función cumple el segundo pero no se que objeto llama this o que funcion
        cumple el primero*/
        this.cache.bitmapFont.add('gamma', Phaser.GameObjects.RetroFont.Parse(this, config));
        console.log(Phaser.GameObjects.RetroFont.Parse)
        this.texto = this.add.bitmapText(10, 10, 'gamma', 'VALOR: 0');
    }
}
export default Bootloader;
```

Comment: Mmm, probablemente funcione solo pasándole config. This es solo una referencia al propio objeto RetroFont.

Comment: Cuando le quito this y dejo solo config deja de funcionar me dicen la consola de firefox: e is undefined T.T